# How to get resource capcity from external source in AnyLogic 7?

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I have a simple simulation which should "test run" a shift schedule result.
My problem is to get the shift output (standalone java program) into AnyLogic.

Are there any possibilities? I would prefer AnyLogic to run the shift planner and use the return value as input.

I use AnyLogic 7 with multiple resource pools for which each capacity changes over time of day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use csv values and read them through plain java.